# Vue.js: load component from another component in javascript during initial page load

Tags: python, django, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm really new to Vue.js so please be patient.

Trying to create a page with a Vue.js component, that will have other child components. Managed to create and load the first outer component, but I'm having trouble to load the child/inner components. The main project is made using python Django and my code is below. Made several attempts with the `import` instruction, but always endup with an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` message in the javascript console. Anyone can help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

---

Django template:

**teleconsultoria/templates/teleconsultoria/registro_consultoria_0800.html**

```
...
          <div class="col s12 bibliografia">
             <div class="row" id="caixa-de-referencias">
               <div class="input-field col s6">
                 <textarea id="textarea-bibliografia" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                 <label for="textarea-bibliografia">Bibliografia</label>
               </div>

               <list items=items></list>

             </div>
           </div>
...

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
 <script src="{% static 'core/js/componentes_vue/list.js' %}"></script>
 <script>
 var appts2 = new Vue({
   el: '#caixa-de-referencias',
   data: {
     items: [
       'referenciA 1',
       'referenciA 2',
     ]
   }
 });
 </script>
```

---

List of items component:

**core/static/core/js/componentes_vue/list.js**

```
import collection_item from './collection_item.js';

var list = Vue.component('list', {
  props: ['items'],
  template: `
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="search">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
          <input id="search-bibliografia" placeholder="Referências (sugestões)">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </div>

        <ul class="collection with-header search-results">
          <li class="collection-header"><p>Sugestões baseadas na "hipotese"</p></li>
          <collection-item v-for="item in items"></collection-item>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>`
});
```

---

Item component:

**core/static/core/js/componentes_vue/collection_item.js**

```
var collectionItem = Vue.component('collection-item', {
  props: ['texto'],
  template: `
    <li class="collection-item">
      <div>
        <a href="#!" class="link-inserir tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">
          {{ texto }}
        </a>
        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content" target="_blank">
          <i class="material-icons">launch</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>`
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
import collection_item from './collection_item.js';
```

from list.js.

Then add the collection_item.js to your page.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="{% static 'core/js/componentes_vue/collection_item.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'core/js/componentes_vue/list.js' %}"></script>
 <script>
 var appts2 = new Vue({
   el: '#caixa-de-referencias',
   data: {
     items: [
       'referenciA 1',
       'referenciA 2',
     ]
   }
 });
 </script>
```

Vue.component exposes a component *globally*.

This will get you past your current error. It looks like there are other errors in your template as posted.

```
<list items=items></list>
```

should be

```
<list v-bind:items="items"></list>
```

Also there should be a `texto` property in `<collection-item v-for="item in items"></collection-item>`. Also, Vue will complain in development mode that there is [no `key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) when you iterate over a component.

Comment: Awesome! Not only that worked, you also set me on track to fix other issues. Thanks @Bert!